# Why does wrapping a redux call into a promise allows the access of the result "immediately"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So we have a redux (with thunk middleware) / react environment.
We have the following piece of code:

```
onMyClick = () => {
    this.props.mySynchronousActionWhichWillCreateNewReducerState();
    this.setState(...my state change which wants to see the new reducer state...);
}
```

It will not work in this form since the code is synchronous. Which means that the react lifecycle will never get to update itself with the new props.
However if we change it like this:

```
onMyClick = () => {
    Promise.resolve(this.props.myActionWichWillCreateNewReducerState())
           .then(
              () => this.setState(...my state change which want to see the new reducer state...)
           );
}
```

It now works as "expected" (The dispatch triggers the new reducer state, the component updates, then the setState runs). First I thought this solution is error prone and works because we 'win' just a bit of time with asynchronicity to allow the update to kick in before the setState. But it never fails, (You can make the code slow in the action, or in the reducer, in the middleware, in the component update, where ever you want, it still works).

**Why?**

---

Some explanation might be warranted why this is so hard to wrap my head around. And more in the sense of "Why does it work the way it does" instead of "How does it work"

So first and foremost lets look at the two pieces of code like plain javascript.
In this case - for me at least - the first should work, and the second should not. Or at least the second should be fuzzy.

First:
 I make **synchronous call** (dispatch->action creation->store change), then I make an other, and yet the second cannot expect the changes made by the first. I have to know how redux and react operates quite intimately to know how, and why. And btw you can even mutate the redux store (big no no) instead of returning a new object from the reducer to retain the reference and it still doesn't work. Which is mind boggling, you synchronously mutate an object, then cannot access the change afterwards...

Second:
 In this case (just like Jaromanda X commented) what I "seemingly" tell the code 'Hey run these two pieces of code in parallel'. And now it works, and works all the time. Wut. Adding my (superficial or so it seems) understanding of react life cycles to the mix makes it even more paradoxical. Since it means that even more logic - react lifecycle update - will have to 'outrun' the setState call for it to work.

If this wouldn't be redux/react environment with all the support and intelligence behind it, I would say this code behavior smells like all hell and it smells like black-magic and go-to :).

Comment: you could do the same with setTimeout - so it's not because of the Promise by any stretch

Answer (score 1):

When you wrap a piece of code inside a promise, you are essentially delaying its execution by a minimum of 1 tick. For your code, that time was sufficient enough for `reducer dispatch` to complete its update. Hence when the code inside `then` was executed it got the updated value, as `this.state` is an object and even within a closure it always points to a memory reference which will be updated.

That said neither reducer update in redux or `setState` in React returns a promise. Your code is equivalent to :

```
Promise.resolve(console.log("dummy")).then(() => console.log("second"));
console.log("first")
```

`first` will always be printed before `second` as the promisified snippet is executed in the next tick of the event queue.

Your code is not error prone at the moment because React decided 1 tick was sufficient to update the state. But don't rely on that as for some other piece of code or in later versions of React, the time required for updates might change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I would like to have some deeper understanding :) So "React decided 1 tick was sufficient to update the state". But what does 1 tick mean? Especially in this context? I tried many things to break this piece of logic by delaying the execution of the action or the reducer, or anything between and thus far failed. Is there an example maybe you can think of which would not allow this behavior to work?

Comment: 1 tick means one cycle of event queue in the JS stack before the next method is executed. Dispatch an action which does something asynchronous in your middleware (like an API call). This would not work as the promise which you wrote above will resolve after firing the action and will not wait for the API call to complete.

Comment: I'm sorry but it absolutely does work :). In that case its even easier because I don't have to manually wrap the dispatch in a Promise in the component since the http call will return with one anyway which then can returned by the redux-thunk. # Also added some explanation what I don't get in the original post.

Comment: It depends on how the promise is formed. In case of thunks, the action creator itself returns the `fetch` promise hence `Promise.resolve` waits till completion. But say you called a function which does not return a promise, this approach will fail. Try creating a function which makes a simple `fetch` and logs its result. Do not return any promise back. Now call this function from `Promise.resolve`.